# How do i decrypt after wards in npm

Tags: node.js, encryption, sha

I have the example from nodejs.org for the file encryption

```
const fs = require('fs');

const algorithm = 'aes-192-cbc';
const password = 'Password used to generate key';
// Use the async `crypto.scrypt()` instead.
const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, 'salt', 24);
// Use `crypto.randomBytes()` to generate a random iv instead of the static iv
// shown here.
const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0); // Initialization vector.

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);

const input = fs.createReadStream('test.js');
const output = fs.createWriteStream('test.enc');

input.pipe(cipher).pipe(output);
}
```

How do i do the oposite and get test.enc to test.js using the same key?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I will answer your question with a question. In the documentation, what is the method that is directly after `crypto.createCipheriv()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a similar process to decrypt the file that you have encrypted using the above code.

We'll write the decrypted file to "test-decoded.js" so we don't end up overwriting our original file.

I'd also point out that you should ideally populate the IV with a random value and store this with the encrypted data, though if you're just testing it doesn't really matter too much!

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require("crypto");

const algorithm = 'aes-192-cbc';
const password = 'Password used to generate key';
const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, 'salt', 24);
const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0); // Initialization vector.

const decryptInput = fs.createReadStream('test.enc');
const decryptOutput = fs.createWriteStream('test-decoded.js');
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
decryptInput.pipe(decipher).pipe(decryptOutput);
```